# Улучшение раздела справки «Что такое защищенные вопросы?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: Protect Questions
Ссылка на текущую версию на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions

---

#### What are protected questions?

A [protected question prevents answers being added by anonymous and very new users.

Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.

#### Which questions can be protected?

Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege, provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation (such users would then be prevented from posting further answers after the question is protected).

Comment: Ссылка потерялась

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заголовок: Защищённые вопросы
Ссылка на текущую версию на русском: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions

---

#### Что такое защищённые вопросы?

Если [вопрос защищён](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/), то анонимные пользователи и новые участники не могут добавлять ответы на него. Вопросы стоит защищать, если они набирают много просмотров, и новички пишут «у меня тоже самое!», «спасибо!», или даже публикуют спам.

#### Какие вопросы можно защитить?

Участники, имеющие соответствующие привилегии, могут защитить, или наоборот, отменить защиту любого вопроса, опубликованного не позднее, чем один день назад, при условии, что на вопрос уже имеется ответ от участника с репутацией менее 10 баллов.

Comment: Вроде бы говорили, что будет на сайте. Но до сих пор нет.

Comment: @alexolut  Спасибо! Теперь все на своих местах!

Comment: почему-то в заголовках попрежнему без "ё"

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо! Поправил!

Comment: почему так получилось? Заголовки отдельно хранятся?

Comment: @alexolut Да, отдельно.